# Limiting Elasticsearch heap memory size with environment variables

Tags: docker, elasticsearch

I'm trying to limit Elasticsearch JVM heap size.

I have a custom docker image (just added some plugins) and to start it up, I'm using this following line:

```
docker run --name elastic-search -d -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 --env-file=elastic-docker.properties build-server/my-elastic:latest
```

docker.properties file looks like this:

```
discovery.type=single-node
bootstrap.memory_lock=true
xpack.security.enabled=true
ELASTIC_USERNAME=elastic
ELASTIC_PASSWORD=changeme
ES_JAVA_OPTS="-Xms2g -Xmx2g"
```

But setting `ES_JAVA_OPTS` as such gets me `Error: Could not find or load main class "-Xms2g`. I tried with combinations of `ES_JAVA_OPTS=".bin/my-elastic -Xms2g -Xmx2g"`, but did not manage to get anywhere.

Any help is appreciated, I would really prefer to do this through environment options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like quotation marks were at fault here. It should actually be listed as `ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms2g -Xmx2g` in environment file.